# List all the folders in a bucket - boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm working on a lambda function for which I need list of all the folders in a S3 bucket. I need to be able to traverse the each folder and get all the subfolders until the end of the tree is reached.

I implemented this by calling `list_objects_v2` function recursively with different prefixes in `boto3` and while it does work it is very slow and for buckets with alot of folders the lambda is exceeding the timeout of 15 minutes.

I wanted to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

**Update**: Sample output, this is what I'm getting right now by calling `list_objects_v2` recursively.

```
L1/
L1/hist/
L1/hist/2022-01-03
L1/hist/2022-01-01
...
```

**Update 2**: Even after using a paginator like mentioned in the answers below, some buckets have so many objects that the lambda is still exceeding 15 min timeout. I'm not sure how to tackle this, please help!

Comment: Why do you need recursion? Just call `list_objects_v2` once and then process the output.

Comment: Please update your Question to show an example of the 'output' you want from your function. For example, is it a _list_ of folders? Does each folder have the full path (eg `['invoices/january', 'invoices/february']`), or do you just want the folder names (eg `['invoices', 'january', 'february']`)? How are you going to use this information? I ask this because we need to know the output to recommend the most efficient way to derive it.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I've added a sample output

Comment: @Marcin If I do `list_objects_v2` once I only get the list of top level objects in the bucket. So I need to call it again for each folder that I get.

Comment: There are no folders in S3. `list_objects_v2` returns every key in the S3 bucket. Its only up to you to define what part of a key is a "folder" or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can enumerate through all of the objects in the bucket, and find the "folder" (really the prefix up until the last delimiter), and build up a list of available folders:

```
seen = set()
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket='bucket-name'):
    for obj in page.get('Contents', []):
        key = obj['Key']
        folder = key[:key.rindex("/")] if '/' in key else ""
        if folder not in seen:
            seen.add(folder)
            print(folder)
```

Alternatively, you could use the same basic logic of recursion that you were using, only with multiple workers, allowing you to alleviate some of the time spent waiting for replies:

```
def recursion_worker(bucket_name, prefix):
    # Look in the bucket at the given prefix, and return a list of folders
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')

    folders = []
    for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter='/'):
        for sub_prefix in page.get('CommonPrefixes', []):
            folders.append(sub_prefix['Prefix'])
        # S3 returns common prefixes first, if there are any objects, it 
        # means further pages will just return objects, so no need
        # to keep going
        # Note that this isn't a garuanteed order, though it's unlikely
        # to change. To be 100% safe, don't do this check at the expense
        # of a slower result set for large buckets
        if len(page.get('Contents', [])) > 0:
            break

    return folders

def folders_via_recursion():
    import multiprocessing
    from collections import deque

    bucket_name = 'example-bucket'
    folders = []
    # Spin up many workers, more than we have CPU cores for
    # since most of the workers will be spending most
    # of their time waiting for network traffic
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=32) as pool:
        pending = deque()
        # Seed the workers with the first request to list objects at
        # the root of the bucket
        pending.append(pool.apply_async(recursion_worker, (bucket_name, "")))
        while len(pending) > 0:
            # Keep going while there are items to parse
            temp = pending.popleft()
            for cur in temp.get():
                # Print out every folder, and store the result in an array
                # to consume later on
                print(cur)
                folders.append(cur)
                # And tell a free worker to list out the folder we just found
                pending.append(pool.apply_async(recursion_worker, (bucket_name, cur)))

    # All done, we can consume the folders array as needed, though
    # do note, it's in a somewhat random order, run something like
    # folders.sort()
    # first if you want a stable order before looking at it
```

If even this fails, then your bucket is simply too big to parse in one go in a Lambda.  You'll need to consider some other solution to get a list of files, like using [AWS S3 Inventory](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/building-a-central-asset-register-with-amazon-s3-inventory/) to create a list of objects outside of this Lambda that it can process.

Comment: Nicer code than mine!

Comment: I've implemented this solution with paginator but still my lambda is exceeding the timeout limit since there are just too many objects in the bucket. How can I handle this?

Comment: @AmolBorkar One possibility is to use multiple workers to enumerate the bucket, I've added some example code.  If even that fails, then you'll need to use some other non-Lambda solution, such as AWS Inventory, or an EC2 helper to list the bucket.

Comment: Recursively fetching common prefixes is what I was doing earlier, I'll try it with multiple workers, Thanks

Comment: Just a heads up to anyone trying this, AWS Lambda doesn't support `multiprocessing.Pool()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `list_objects_v2()` call returns a list of all objects. The `Key` of each object includes the full path of the object.

Therefore, you can simply extract the paths from the Keys of all objects:

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my-bucket')

# folder1/folder2/foo.txt --> folder1/folder2
paths = {object['Key'][:object['Key'].rfind('/')] for object in response['Contents'] if '/' in object['Key']}

for path in sorted(paths):
    print(path)
```

If your bucket contains more than 1000 objects, then you will either need to loop through the results using `ContinuationToken` or use a **paginator**. See: [`list_objects_v2` paginator](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Paginator.ListObjectsV2)